# CI Route confliction

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

I am having a hard time in figuring out how to make a route for this case: `http://wwww.domain.com/category-slug/product-slug` i thought it was en easy task and i quickly add this line in `route.php`

`$route['([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)'] = "products/show";`

but, this is is also redirecting me on every page like `http://wwww.domain.com/admin/dashboard` and so on but, i explicitly want to use only for my products. How to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because,  first segment `admin` and `dashboard` in the second matches `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` ,and remapped to the `products` class/controller and the `show` method/function.

If you can create url like something

```
products/category-slug/product-slug
```

Then if you set route like below

```
$route['products/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)'] = 'products/show/$1/$2';
```

Comment: No i dont want to use products keyword in my route.

Comment: Routes are executed in order, so you set route for your admin controller first   and then for your products, easiest way is to create URL like above...   Otherwise how do you identify url is intended for products controller

Comment: Can you tell me how to use database queries in `route.php`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use something like this

```
$route['products/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Product_controller/product_function/$1/$2'
```

Inside your function you can have something like this

```
public function product_function(cat_slug, pro_slug){
     //Some code here
}
```